# Espresso testing with ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-espresso, android-testing, expandablelistadapter

I'm using espresso as my `UI` automation test. I want to create a `matcher` for `ExpandableListView`, since it sometimes goes of screen and its not good practice to call `onView(withText("something"))` on a view that has `adapter` bound to it. Can somebody show me how to create `matcher` for `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [accessing children in custom expandablelist using android espresso](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220612/accessing-children-in-custom-expandablelist-using-android-espresso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this one would be useful, but:

> ```
>  public static Matcher<Object> withListItemCheck(final <Type> check_value) {
>     checkNotNull(check_value);
>     return new BoundedMatcher<Object, <List_Item_class>>(<List_Item_class>.class) {
>         private String m_message = "";
>
>         @Override
>         public void describeTo(Description d) {
>             d.appendText(m_message);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public boolean matchesSafely(<List_Item_class> listItem) {
>             m_message = "Expected " + listItem+ " and got ";
>             if (listItem== null) {
>                 m_message +=  "empty";
>                 return false;
>             }
>             return <assertion to check `check_value` is corresponding to `listItem` or not>;
>         }
>     };
> }
> ```
>
> Taken from: [accessing children in custom expandablelist using android espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220612/accessing-children-in-custom-expandablelist-using-android-espresso)

Hope it will help